# Is it possible to add a check box to the terms and conditions when registering

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community, register

Is it possible to add a check box to the terms and conditions when registering in this page (/customer/account/create/) ?

Comment: Yes, I had the same question answered.

Comment: With magento basic? afaik no.

Comment: It's not on checkout but when the user is registering. It's not possible Fabian ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

1. Add the terms attribute via a set-up script, unless you already have this attribute.
2. Update your template to show the new checkbox and make it match your design,
3. If you make this attribute used in registration form then it should save after these two changes,